# Console Log different with variable then formula in console.log()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm using javascript and calling an API which returns some JSON. For some reason, when I assign the JSON to a variable, it removes some of the data. If I console log the variable (in this case data2) it is not the same output as when I just put a function JSON.parse(data) inside the console log.

```
    let data = await res.text();
    console.log("data1: ",JSON.parse(data))
    const  data2 =  JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("data2: ",data2);
```

Both console logs should be the same but they are not.
[image]

I've tried everything to figure this out but in the end my understanding is the console should be printing the exact same thing

All of this code is in a function so it shouldn't be reused or mutated (that I'm aware of). The full function is here (cleaned up and using res.josn())

```
  const post = async (url, params) => {
    const res = await fetch(BASE_URL + url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(params),
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log("data1: ",data)
    return data1;
  };
```

In this case, the data variable is incomplete and not showing the full response

Comment: Do you edit `data` or `data2` later in the code? Console doesn't show the current state of objects, not from when they were logged

Comment: Aside, why do you use `res.text` instead of `res.json`?

Comment: specifically, I would guess that `data2` is being mutated at some point after it's logged. `data` can't be because it's a (JSON) string and what's being logged (the object or array parsed from it) isn't being assigned to any variable that could be mutated

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! I'm using res.text instead of res.json so that I can do some console logs and see where in the process its failing (I had assumed it was the json parser that wasn't working). I'll edit my question with more details too thanks

Comment: Are you certain that you are looking at exactly the same key inside `availableSlots` in both cases? Key order is not guaranteed in JS.

Comment: You return `data` so you probably modify it later. Returning from a function doesn't create a new reference